# Siamese network assigns same label to every couple of images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, siamese-network

I'm working on a siamese network to identify if the input images are the same picture or not.
The problem is that the network keep assigning the label 0 (rather than 0 and 1) resulting in 0.5 accuracy every time but I don't know why.

Here's the model:

```
def Model():

  input_dim = (200, 200, 1)
  img_a = Input(shape = input_dim)
  img_b = Input(shape = input_dim)

  base_net = build_base_network(input_dim)

  features_a = base_net(img_a)
  features_b = base_net(img_b)

  distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape = eucl_dist_output_shape)([features_a, features_b])
  model = Model(inputs=[img_a, img_b], outputs=distance)

  return model
```

And here's the distance

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  margin = 1
  return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

#Optimizer
rms = RMSprop()

#Distance
def euclidean_distance(vects):
  x, y = vects
  return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))

def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)
```

Training and X/y shapes

```
#Pair_equal --> every element is a tuple of numpy arrays representing same images
#Pair_diff --> every element is a tuple of numpy arrays representing different images
#y_equal --> for every Pair equal's element, contains 0
#y_diff --> for every Pair equal's element, contains 1

  if len(Pair_equal) > len(Pair_diff):
    Pair_equal = Pair_equal[0:len(Pair_diff)]
    y_equal = y_equal[0:len(y_diff)]

  elif len(Pair_equal) < len(Pair_diff):
    Pair_diff = Pair_diff[0:len(Pair_equal)]
    y_diff = y_diff[0:len(y_equal)]

  Pair_equal = np.array(Pair_equal)
  Pair_diff = np.array(Pair_diff)
  y_equal = np.array(y_equal)
  y_diff = np.array(y_diff)

  X = np.concatenate([Pair_equal, Pair_diff], axis=0)
  y = np.concatenate([y_equal, y_diff], axis=0)

  y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

  #index shuffling
  indices = np.arange(X.shape[0])
  np.random.shuffle(indices)

  X = X[indices]
  y = y[indices]
 
  #X shape: (32, 2, 200, 200, 1)
  #y shape: (32, 1)

  return [X[:,0,...], X[:,1,...]], y
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you predicting?

Comment: With "predict = model.predict_generator(training_generator, batch_size, verbose = 1)"

Comment: pls also add the training code and shapes of X_train and Y_train

Comment: If yoy need anything else please ask

Comment: That (32) is very less example to train NN.

Comment: Are you using model.fit() to train?

Comment: Tried with 128, but the result is the same. I'm using fit_generator

Comment: Everything seems correct in here, try to check build_base_network

Comment: I tried to use VGG instead of my network, but it seems that the model doesn't learn anything. (I checked the input images, but everything seems correct)

Comment: One thing you could do to check is try giving image pairs all with y=1. Then too, if your model predicts 0, then there is problem in your network (it is losing/dropping features somewhere in between)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it as soon as possible